# Vue Nested Objects with V-For Computed Property

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs3, pinia

I seem to have run into an issue. my inner v-for is not being consistent with the ordering once it has changed. It shuffles every update.

I have a computed property called "List"
This retrieves a state in my Pinia (vuex type) Store. The object is:

```js
List: {
  CategoryOne: {
    item: false,
    item2: true,
    item3: false,
    item4: true
  },
  CategoryTwo: {
    item: false,
    item2: true,
    item3: false,
    item4: true
  }
}
```

In my first v-for, is as follows...

```html
<div v-for="(value, index, key) in List" :key="key">
  <h1>{{ index }}</h1>
    <ul v-for="(value2, index2, key2) in value" :key="key2">
      <li>
        {{ index2 }} : {{ value2 }}
      </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The problem is, my inner v-for keeps getting shuffled everytime on refresh or update. Why is this???

Comment: It's `value, key, index`, not `value, index, key`. It's not known if the order of fields stays the same in the place where data comes from. Generally it's unsafe to rely on the order of fields in JS. If you need strictly ordered data, use sets or arrays